# How to calculate a new length?

Tags: calculations, lengths

What I want to do is calculate the actual size between the edge of the paper, and my header. `\evenmarginsize` and `\oddmarginsize` do not do this.

```
\settowidth{\msize}{((\paperwidth - \textwidth)/2)}
```

Doesn't seem to work, how can this be done?

Comment: 1. You don't say which edge of the paper. On first reading, because you are talking about the header, I thought the top edge. 2. The commands `\evenmarginsize` and `\oddmarginsize` don't exist. Perhaps you meant `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin`. 3. `\settowidth` takes a piece of text and calculates its width. For what you want, use `\setlength` and you need the `calc` package to use algebraic notation. 4. One more thing: supply a compilable file that shows what you tried.

Comment: 1) The left hand side, when I first tried this I didn't think it mattered. 2) Yes, those are the correct commands. My memory mixed them up. 3) Below is a solution without calc. 4) Didn't need to. Oh, and one more thing, calm the attitude Mr. Keyboard Warrior.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the e-TeX structure:

```
\newlength{\msize}
\setlength{\msize}{\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2\relax}
```

The macro `\settowidth` is used with finding the width of a portion of text such as in:

```
 \newlength{\mytextwidth}
 \settowidth{\mytextwidth}{This is some text whose width I'm measuring}
```

The documentation can be found by running `texdoc etex` from the command line.  Amoung other things, e-TeX provides several nice commands to facilitate calculations using `\dimexpr`, `\numexpr`, and several other flavors.  Since I've discovered these, I find I don't use the `calc` package that much anymore.

Comment: Documentation Please :)!

Answer (score 10):

```
\usepackage{calc}

...

\setlength{\msize}{0.5\paperwidth-0.5\textwidth}
```

However, I recommend you looking at the `hcentering` option of the [package `geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/goemetry).

Comment: Not trying to centre the header.

Comment: Well, you obviously do some calculation of the page geometry. I only suggest that you might have a look at the package above, because you might save yourself a lot of time not doing something that has been done before ;)

Comment: Haha I checked it out, it wasn't what I wanted. Thank you though